# Disable url correction / rewriting by codeigniter for SEO

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, seo

I have CI 1.6 installed, with basic url library and usual config/routes.php file.
But in my case all of the following urls works:

```
mysite.com/products/id/919330  
mysite.com/products/id/919330/  
mysite.com//products/id/919330 - (see double slash!)  
mysite.com/products///id/919330/ - (even this!)
```

As my SEO-guy says that i need to redirect them all to the first variant
**mysite.com/products/id/919330** or to give 404 by all except the first one.

Where i could try to make corrections to disable this clever URL detecting by CI?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   $url = $this->uri->segment(n);
   if($url[0]=="products" && $url[1]=="id"){
         // Do this stuff;
    }else{
        // redirect to 404;
    }
```

For futher information [Check this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: sorry, i've got plenty of controllers/url schemes so this is not good decision